# Why this is syntax error? How can I fix this (Python)

Tags: python, syntax-error

Hello I am new to programming can you please tell why this is syntax error and how can I fix this.Check the picture
P.s Sorry for foregain language

```
**a**=int(input("Įvesk pradžios intervalo skaitmenį"))
b=int(input("Įvesk pabaigos intervalo skaitmenį"))
c=str(a)
c=len(c)
if c!=3 or a<0 or a>b**:**
    print ("Klaida. Skaičiai negali būti neigiami, jie turi būti    triženkliai, intervalo pradžia neturi būti didesnė už pabaigą /n Įvesk   skaičius iš naujo"
    a=int(input("Įvesk pradžios intervalo skaitmenį"))
    b=int(input("Įvesk pabaigos intervalo skaitmenį"))
for x in range (a,b+1):
    x=str(x)
    f=len(x)
    f=int(f)
    s=0
    for m range(0,f):
        x=str(x)
        a=x[m]
        a=int(a)
        s=s+a
        if s<=5:
            print(x,"Nenusimink")
        elif 5<s<=8:
            print(x,"Pasistenk")
        elif s>8:
            print(x,"Pergalė")
```

Comment: Please post your code as text, not as an image.

Comment: Probably because you forgot to close a parenthesis or quote on the preceding line, which we cannot tell because you posted a picture instead of typing your code directly in the question.

Comment: Please, do remove your image. It is unnecessary. Mark the line where the error occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple syntax errors in your code, but the one that is raising in your IDLE is because of not closing the parentheses you've opened. Write it as follows:

```
  print ("Klaida...") # note the parentheses closing

  a=int(input("Įvesk pradžios intervalo skaitmenį"))
  b=int(input("Įvesk pabaigos intervalo skaitmenį"))

...
```

The other syntax error is, as Daniel Bober pointed out, the `for m in range(a, b+1):` syntax error, where you missed the `in` keyword.

Please, do re-check your code before posting questions in SO. That is something you could have fixed being more careful.

Comment: @Kristupas By the way, this line seems to be wrong as well, but I can't tell because I don't really understand it. `if c!=3 or a<0 or a>b**:**`.

Comment: Thank you alot <3

Answer (score 1):

`for m in range(a, b+1):`  you missed `in` keyword

Comment: Sorry, i can't add a comment to your question. And post your code as text next time